# Testing the Appearance of Web Applications

Tags: system-testing

#### Duplicate:

> - [Testing a website for cross-browser/multiple-version support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462848/testing-a-website-for-cross-browser-multiple-version-support)
> - [How do you test visual components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351975/how-do-you-test-visual-components)

---

I recently talked to a colleague about a tool we use at work for system testing web applications.  The colleague then raised the question as to whether we tested the appearance of the application.

Does anyone else do this and if so, how would one test it to ensure things don't get moved out of place or that things are the correct dimensions etc?

Comment: Are you talking manual testing, or some sort of automated comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check what your website looks like in many different browsers checkout [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/).

Answer (score 0):

One of my clients was already set up with [Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/) when I got there and that project was a breeze to work on. So smooth.

I'd like to be able to roll my own system like that, though. It's too bad they don't sell the actual software - just the service.